# how to port python urllib2 app (a web scraper) that uses Beautiful Soup 4 to use requests package instead

Tags: python-requests, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to update web scraper app that uses Beautiful Soup 4 in Python 3 in Anaconda to use the Requests package instead of urllib, urllib2 and urllib3.

urllib and urllib2 don't exist in the Anaconda channels and from what I have read requests package has made urllib and urllib2 obsolete.  I am still rather new in Python programming for web scraping, and don't yet fully understand all concepts and internal subtleties of these 4 packages.

When I replace "urllib2.urlopen()" with "requests.get()", I get the following error:

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
'''replace the following line with "page =  Request.get(url)" '''
#   page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
page = requests.get(url)
soup_page = BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")
```

I get the following error message with no explanation in the bs4 module:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4__init__.py", line 246, in **init**
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (

TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

This error message puts me deep into the bowels of **init**.py in bs4.

I cannot find an explanation of how to port urllib or urllib2 code to requests with Beautiful Soup 4.

Can anyone provide an explicit guide on how to port urllib / urllib2 apps to use requests with beautiful soup in Python 3?

Anaconda / conda does not import urllib or urllib2 into Python 3 environments.

Thank you.

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you're trying to pass the html code of the response to Beautifulsoup in the wrong way. Pass `response.text`, instead of the response object:

```
# page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

page = requests.get(url)

soup_page = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
```

You may need to read [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I got it to work with Requests lib rather than urllib2.  I find the Requests package much cleaner and error-free than the urllib packages (urllib1, urllib2, and urllib3).